# How to alter multiple nodes in a DTSX xml file with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to do the following: Select the `Configuration` nodes and, depending on the `ObjectName` value, change the `ConfigurationString` node value.

The XML is the following:

```
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/.." DTS:ExecutableType="SSIS.Package">  
  <DTS:Configuration>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationType">1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationString">change me</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">Configuration_1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{..}</DTS:Property>
  </DTS:Configuration>
  <DTS:Configuration>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationType">1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationString">me to please</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">Configuration_2</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{..}</DTS:Property>
  </DTS:Configuration>
```

I had the following code to alter the ConfigurationString when there was only one instance of this type of node.

```
$item = [xml](Get-Content -Path($item_path))
$item.Executable.Configuration.Property | ? { $_.name -eq 'configurationstring'} | % { $_.'#text' = "text" }
$item.Save( $item_path )
```

I tried to add a condition at `? { $_.name -eq 'configurationstring'}` to check if the `ObjectName` was the desired one, but I couldn't get back to the `Configuration` node and change the `ConfigurationString` node value.

I have also tried using the `SelectSingleNode` method, but it didn't work:

```
$item.SelectSingleNode("Executable/Configuration/Property[@ObjectName='Configuration_1']") | ? { $_.name -eq 'configurationstring'} | % { $_.'#text' = "test" }
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple matter of using `SelectSingleNode` to get the parent

```
 $xml.Executable.Configuration | % { $_.property } | # Get all of the properties
  ? { $_.name -eq "ObjectName" -and $_."#text" -eq "Configuration_1" } | #Get the one we are looking for 
  % { $_.selectSingleNode("..").Property } | # Get all of it's sibling properties
  ? { $_.name -eq 'configurationstring'} |   # Get the property we want to change
  % { $_.'#text' = "text" }                  # Update property
```

It's maybe not the cleanest but it should get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, the problem maintains. If I use your code with only one `DTS:Configuration`, it works, but when there are +1 `DTS:Configuration`, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try again, it was using a feature of V3 but you are using v2

Answer (score 0):

```
    PS C:\> $item.Executable.Configuration | % { $_.ChildNodes.GetEnumerator() } | ? {$_.Name -eq "ConfigurationString"} | % { $_.'#text' = "sometext"}

$item.Save("C:\Scripts\so\dtsx.xml")
```